# Speeding up groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like the following code to run faster (maybe using numpy ?) but I can't figure out how to do it :

```
        df = df[['shop_id', 'brand', 'industry', 'zip_code', 'impressions', 'is_retailer']].groupby(
        ['shop_id', 'zip_code', 'brand']).agg(
        {'impressions': 'sum', 'is_retailer': 'sum', 'industry': 'max'}).reset_index()
```

Basically, I want to group by a dataframe by shop_id, zip_code and brand, and perform a sum over the impressions and the column "is_retailer" and select the max of the industry.

Is there a faster way to do it? I need to perform this operation several times.

Thanks

Comment: df.groupby( ['shop_id', 'zip_code', 'brand'], as_index=False,sort=False) you can add these 2 parameters to enhance performance. Indexing/sorting is turned on by default so by turning it off you can achieve some performance gain

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output